# VB.NET Report Viewer Issue

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, reporting-services

So I have a report server in a local area network that I want to access via a winform application with a Report viewer

my Report viewer control Name is rpt_ReportViewer
and here's the Code to view reports on the reportviewer rpt_ReportViewer

```
    Private Sub rpt_GenerateReportBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles rpt_GenerateReportBtn.Click
    With rpt_ReportViewer
        .ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri("http://SERVER/ReportServer")
        .ServerReport.ReportPath = "/Search Assets Table/Search Assets Table"
        .RefreshReport()
    End With
End Sub
```

whenever I run this code it generates an exception in the report viewer saying "The Request Failed with HTTP Status 401: Unauthorized."

I don't know whats wrong but I used this very same code on a localhost and it worked http://localhost/reportserver

can anyone help me figuring out whats wrong please ? thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you may need to provide user credentials as well.

Comment: @Karlta05 thanks I solved it and you are right it needed credentials to access the server

Comment: You should post your solution to help any others that may encounter the same problem that you had. Glad you solved it as well. :D

Comment: Done , and thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's the solution

```
        Dim Credential As New NetworkCredential("User name", "Password") 'Was missing this Line
    With rpt_ReportViewer
        .ServerReport.ReportServerCredentials.NetworkCredentials = Credential 'Was missing this line too
        .ServerReport.ReportServerUrl = New Uri("http://SERVER/ReportServer")
        .ServerReport.ReportPath = rpt_ReportsListBox.SelectedValue
        .RefreshReport()
    End With
```